# I need to populate current username in the "Username" field of Identity Server custom login page

Tags: c#, html, identityserver3

In the link below for Identity Server 3,I have to fill username and password to login.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/login.html

But,what I need is that username should be filled automatically before login page flashes on screen with Window's username of the system.For this,I tried the following which I have presented here as well as in a answer to this question:

But that works only in Internet explorer because it has ActiveX which is only supported in Internet explorer.I need to somehow pass
(System.Environment.Username) <-gives me the current user which I need to pass into login page

Comment: `System.Environment.Username` will give you the user name of the user who logged into the computer, which is probably not what you want to use on a web site.  For a server, this is probably `IISUser`, or possibly (hopefully not) `Administrator`.

Comment: @Neil if you look at the link which I shared,I need to populate username in login page.Will IISUser give me user's name and can I write something like: <input required contenteditable="true" name="username" autofocus id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-init="model.username = model.username || (IISUser)" ng-model="model.username"  maxlength="100">                    in html page?

Comment: No, `System.Environment.Username` gives you YOUR name when you run it locally because YOU are logged into the computer the code is running on.  If I visit your web site, are you expecting it to use MY user name?  If so, that's not how the web sites works.

Comment: Yeah ,true but can you suggest any change I can make in the login.html page for Identity server through which I can get current username populated on login page load in login screen

Comment: I don't think there is a way.   When I log in on different web sites, I use 2 or 3 different email addresses for different purposes (one for work, one for home etc).  How would that work on your web site, which 'name' would it choose?

Comment: Something like:                             <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                                            <input required contenteditable="true" name="username" autofocus id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-init="model.username = model.username || (WinNetwork.UserName)" ng-model="model.username"  maxlength="100">
                                        </div>    .Please have a look at source code which I have provided.Iam trying to modify it as per my requirement

Comment: @Neil it should  be able to read and display your Windows username

Comment: What if I'm using a Mac, or Linux, or a mobile phone?  None of these things that can access a web site, have a Windows username.

Comment: @Neil I just need Windows,so if any solution is specific to Windows ,it is fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function GetUsername()
{
var wshshell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
                var username = wshshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%");
                document.getElementById("username").value  = username;
}
</script>

I called this method from <body lang="en" onload="GetUserName()">  but this only gives current username in Internet explorer. Please someone suggest me better answer if they have any idea.
```